# Tests with @javascript not working in Sylius (plugin)

Tags: behat, sylius

I have been facing this issue for more than a day now, and I can't seem to figure it out.

I have configured my plugin using docker and I am running behat with headless chrome, getting this:

```
docker-compose exec -e APP_ENV=test sylius_plugin bash -c "vendor/bin/behat features/user/managing_vendors/deleting_multiple_vendors.feature"

@managing_vendors
Feature: Deleting multiple vendors
    In order to get rid of deprecated vendors in an efficient way
    As an Administrator
    I want to be able to delete multiple vendor accounts at once

  Background:                                                           
    Given I am logged in as an administrator                            
    And there is a vendor "ted" whose email is "ted@example.com"       
    And there is also a vendor "john" whose email is "john@example.com"

  @ui @javascript
  Scenario: Deleting multiple vendors at once                         
    Given I browse vendors                                            
      Expected to be on "http://0.0.0.0:80/admin/vendor-users/" but found "http://0.0.0.0/admin/login" instead (FriendsOfBehat\PageObjectExtension\Page\UnexpectedPageException)
```

This feature is based on deleting_multiple_administrators.feature that is provided in the sylius package.

I found this other issue (https://github.com/Sylius/PluginSkeleton/issues/138) and tried to apply those solutions but none worked.

Could you enlighten me on this?

Happy to provide additional info.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I have found the problem. There was a conflict between the environments (and therefore databases) dev and test.

The solution was to separate the environments in two docker containers and run them in an isolated manner.

Comment: What was the conflict about?

Comment: @VictorVasiloi I set up one container with two databases but when running the tests using the headless browser, I was being pointed to the dev application, because that was the only one running. So I just had to set up a new container to run the test application, in a different port.